# Creating Saveable->False notebooks

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, options, windows

**Bug introduced in 10.3 or earlier and fixed in 11.1**

---

**Reproduced on Windows 7, 10**

Bug confirmed by WRI:

> [...] It does appear that the Saveable Notebook Option on Windows is not behaving properly, and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. [...]

---

I'm having difficulties with programmatic creation of non saveable notebooks on Windows with V10.4.1. while I believe it was working in the past.

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.nb"}];

Export[
    path,
    Notebook[{}, Saveable -> False ],
    "NB"
]

NotebookOpen @ path;
```

Now write something there, menu item `File > Save` is inactive but use <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> and close the notebook. Open again:

```
NotebookOpen @ path;
```

**and the edited content is there. (*that is unexpected*)**

> With the setting `Saveable->False`, a notebook cannot be saved using File > Save or the **equivalent keyboard shortcut**.

On the other hand edited Help notebooks are not preserving changes....

#### What have I missed? How are they different?

---

#### Further investigation about Help notebooks.

As mentioned before, they appear to behave correctly. Also their menu is different than menu of just `Saveable->False` notebook:

[image]

`Save As..` item is pale too...

But go to any Help notebook and evaluate e.g:

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "plotRef.nb"}]

CopyFile[ NotebookFileName[], path ]

NotebookOpen @ path
```

The same help notebook opened from desktop is not behaving correctly anymore!

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug, your procedure acts as you expect it to on my system i.e. I can't save changes. MMA 10.0.1.0 OSX 10.10.5 Maybe bug is too strong a word, since the docs say it's subject to change.

Comment: It is not possible to Save with the shortcut for me also (it works as expected) with v10.3.1/v10.4.1 with OSX 10.9.5. It seems an OS specific problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To whom it may concern, a workaround:

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "testWorking.nb"}];

nb = Notebook[{},
   Saveable -> False,
   NotebookEventActions -> {{"MenuCommand", "Save"} :> {}} (*the fix*)
];

Export[path, nb, "NB"]
```

Comment: Thx a lot. So you're overwriting the even actions list where the shortcut _Ctrl+S_ would be defined right?